# Match HTML elements which have two or more <br> elements in a string

Tags: regex

I have to match any string within two `<br>` that are not a direct element of `<p>`. In other words:

> `<p>hello world<br><br>goodbye world</p>` - valid
>
> `<p>hello <span>world<br><br></span>goodbye world</p>` - invalid, should match

After some time, I accomplished this:

```
<p>.*<(?:(?!br>)).*?<br><br>.*?<(?:(.*<\/p>))
```

It is close to do the job, but it fails with, for example:

> `<p>abc<span>abc</span><br><br><span>abc</span></p>` - should be valid

Testing page: http://regexr.com/3c3k8

P.S.: This is to match rows in a database and modify it (I hope) manually. Also, I am not who takes decisions and I have no vote in them.

Comment: Regex and HTML are enemies.

Comment: I know, and I know this is not the way, but the boss is the boss... You know what I mean.

Comment: Boss can be wrong.

Comment: What language are you using?  I imagine that in either PHP or Java it might be easier to build a DOM tree from the input, and inspect it afterwards.

Comment: Yes, I know it... But this is not a democracy. I must do it. Then if the matched results are changed manually or using the regex again is not my decision. Maybe you work in a nice company. It is not my case. @MarounMaroun

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It can be accomplished in JavaScript or VB.NET. I don't know if the matched data will be rearranged manually or not, so I just need the correct regex, forgetting the rest.

Comment: I am looking for `<br><br>` which are **not** direct elements of `<p>`.

Comment: Try [`<p>(?:[^<>]*<\b([\w:-]+)[^<>]*>[^<>]*<br><br>[^<>]*<\/\1>)+[^<>]*<\/p>`](https://regex101.com/r/vV3eK2/1). I understand your situation, and sympathize with you.

Comment: Thank you mate, it's frustrating to work in this kind of companies... That regex match some cases, but not all. Please see at http://regexr.com/3c3k8. There, all of matched elements (in blue) are ok, except the first two (which has the arrow "<---")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't stress enough the reasons why this shouldn't be done with regex. Perhaps this solution serves as a prove on all things that are wrong with a regex approach.

> two `<br>` that are not a direct element of `<p>`
>
> > in JavaScript or VB.NET

The following regex works in [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) and it uses [balancing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html) to validate any number of nested tags:

```
<p>                                         # MAIN Opening <p>
(?>[^<]*)                                   # any text
(?>                                         # BEFORE <br><br>
    [^<]+                                   #  any text
  |                                         #  or
    <                                       #  TAGS
    (?:                                     #   Options:
        !--.*?-->                           #    1. comments
      |                                     #
        \/?\s*(?:area|base|br|col           #    2. self-closing tags
                |embed|hr|img|input         #
                |keygen|link|meta|param     #
                |source|track|wbr           #
              )\b[^>]*\/?>                  #
      |                                     #
        \s*(?<p>p\b)                        #    3. opening nested <p>
      |                                     #
        /\s*(?<-p>p\b)                      #    4. closing nested <p>
      |                                     #
        \s*(?<nestedtag>                    #    5.a) if inside a nested tag:
               (?(nestedtag)\k<nestedtag>   #         another nested tag (same tag)
             |                              #
               [-:\w]+)                     #      b) else: opening nested tag (except <p>)
           \b)                              #      *tag ends with word boundary
      |                                     #
        /\s*(?<-nestedtag>\k<nestedtag>\b)  #    6. closing nested tag
      |                                     #
        (?!/\s*p\b)                         #    7. any other tag except <p> (inside nested tag)
    )                                       #   end of Options
    [^>]*>                                  #  end of TAGS before <br><br>
)*?                                         # repeat as few as possible (BEFORE <br><br>)
(?(nestedtag)(?(p)(?!))|(?!))               # Conditions: unbalanced nested tags and balanced <p>
                                            #
(?:<br>){2}                                 # MATCH: <br><br>
                                            #
(?>[^<]*)                                   # AFTER <br><br> (any text)
(?>                                         #
    [^<]+                                   #  any text
  |                                         #  or
    <                                       #  TAGS
    (?:                                     #   Options:
        (?<p>\s*p\b)                        #    1. opening nested <p>
      |                                     #
        (?<-p>/\s*p\b)                      #    2. closing nested <p>
      |                                     #
        (?!/\s*p\b)                         #    3. any other tag (except the main </p)
    )                                       #   end of Options
    [^>]*>                                  #   rest of tag
)*                                          # repeat as much as possible (AFTER <br><br>)
(?(p)(?!))                                  # Conditions: balanced <p> tags
                                            #
</\s*p\b[^>]*>                              # MAIN Closing </p>
```

---

**[vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) Code**

```vbnet
Dim pattern As String = "<p>(?>[^<]*)(?>[^<]+|<(?:!--.*?-->|/?\s*(?:area|base|br|col|embed|hr|img|input|keygen|link|meta|param|source|track|wbr)\b[^>]*/?>|\s*(?<p>p\b)|/\s*(?<-p>p\b)|\s*(?<nestedtag>(?(nestedtag)\k<nestedtag>|[-:\w]+)\b)|/\s*(?<-nestedtag>\k<nestedtag>\b)|(?!/\s*p\b))[^>]*>)*?(?(nestedtag)(?(p)(?!))|(?!))(?:<br>){2}(?>[^<]*)(?>[^<]+|<(?:(?<p>\s*p\b)|(?<-p>/\s*p\b)|(?!/\s*p\b))[^>]*>)*(?(p)(?!))</\s*p\b[^>]*>"


Dim r As Regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Singleline)

Dim m As Match = r.Match(subject)
Dim matchCount as Integer = 0
Do While m.Success
    matchCount += 1
    Console.WriteLine("Match " & matchCount & ": " & m.Groups(0).ToString())
    m = m.NextMatch()
Loop
```

<kbd>[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fgQDX6)</kbd>

**Ouput**

```
Match 1: <p>hello <span>world<br><br></span>goodbye world</p>
Match 2: <p><p>xxx</p><span><br><br></span></p>
Match 3: <p><span><span>xxx</span><br><br></span></p>
Match 4: <p>asdf<span>asdf<br><br>asdf</span><br><br></p>
Match 5: <p><span>acb<br><br></span>abcd</p>
Match 6: <p>asdf<span>abc<br><br></span></p>
Match 7: <p><STRONG>Cetárea Duromar</STRONG> es una empresa familiar con más de 20 años de experiencia al
servicio de la restauración y el particular <STRONG>brindando siempre la mejor calidad en mariscos
y un esmerado servicio.<BR><BR></STRONG>Hemos sabido adaptarnos a los nuevos tiempos, incorporando
la mejor tecnología, controlando la calidad de nuestro producto, pero sobre todo exigiéndonos a
nosotros mismos ser superiores cada día para poner lo mejor de nuestro mar en su mesa.<BR><BR>Les
ofrecemos una muy <STRONG>cuidada selección del mejor marisco de la ría, de excelente calidad</STRONG>
y con una presentación extraordinaria.<BR><BR>Producto 100% garantizado.</p>
```

<kbd>[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fgQDX6)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you @Mariano, an amazing job. It had to take some time do it and I thank you for it. This approach covers (I think) close to all possibilities so I will accept this as valid answer. Extremely detailed (thanks again), anyone can understand better how the regex works and how to make it step by step. Also, as I said repeatedly, I am not who decides how to do the things. It's more, any programmer here has no vote in any decisions. Sad but it's the truth.

Comment: I totally understand that, as I've found myself in that situation several times. That was a fair warning for any future reader as well.

Answer (score 3):

Regex is certainly not the right tool for this task. You could try [some regex like this](https://regex101.com/r/gL8xV3/1).

```
#p tag and stuff before a tag that includes <br><br>
<p>(?:(?!<\/?p)[\s\S])*?

#capture tag that's not a p tag
<(?!p)(\w+)

  #capture tag only if it's not a singleton tag
  (?=(?:(?!<\/?p)[\s\S])*?<\/\1)[^>]*>

  #don't skip the current tag and find <br><br>
  (?:(?!<\/?(?:p|\1))[\s\S])*<br><br>

#stuff until closing p
[\s\S]*?<\/p>
```

In JS use with i caseless option and without comments.

```
<p>(?:(?!<\/?p)[\s\S])*?<(?!p)(\w+)(?=(?:(?!<\/?p)[\s\S])*?<\/\1)[^>]*>(?:(?!<\/?(?:p|\1))[\s\S])*<br><br>[\s\S]*?<\/p>
```

See explanation on regex101 for further details and be aware, that there's quite some backtracking.

[Here your regexr sample](http://regexr.com/3c462).

Comment: Nice answer. It solves the question and nicely detailed. I know that regex is not the best thing to use, but some project managers are like a wall. Thank you very much.

Comment: welcome @pg02, good it is of help for you and solves trouble!

Comment: There are no nested `<p>` in the strings. The strings are inserted by a text editor, that inserts too many `<br>` and other stuff, but not illegal syntax. Thank you anyway for the note @Mariano.

Comment: It would also fail with any other nested tags like `<p><span><span>xxx</span><br><br></span></p>`

Comment: It's true. The problem of this is that there are too many possibilities and the regex complexity can grow exponentially. Anyway, if this concerns the most "possible cases" it has to serve. Thank you again for pointing possible failures. From here, if I must to continue making more complex the regex, I'll try it. If I need help again, I know where to ask for.